# How do I use an input to print a class definition?

Tags: python, class, input

I am trying to code something basic in python just for fun and I encountered an issue,

```
# Employee is a class with the initialization being self, name, status

e1 = Employee("Tom, Lincoln", "Present")
e2 = Employee("Sam, Bradley", "Absent")
print(e1.status)

# printing e1 status will make "Present" or "Absent"

while True:
    try:
        cmd = input("Cmd: ")

        if cmd == "status_check":
            who = input("Who: ")
            # putting in e1 or e2 will get their respective statuses
```

I've tried everything I can think off like, making it so that it gets a number out of the `input("Who: ")` input so I can better use eval or exac, but doing that makes it so I cant run `e1.status` because all it has is a 1 and I can't make a "e" appear in front of it so I can't run `e1.status`. I've also tried using just eval or exac but that didn't get the wanted result because I would have to type my code in the `input("Cmd: ")`. That's isn't the only things I've tried but those are some that come to mind.

I'm just stumped here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to map names to values, you don't want separate variables. You want a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Rather than

```
e1 = Employee("Tom, Lincoln", "Present")
e2 = Employee("Sam, Bradley", "Absent")
```

Consider

```
employees = {
    'e1': Employee("Tom, Lincoln", "Present"),
    'e2': Employee("Sam, Bradley", "Absent"),
}
```

To access an employee, write

```
print(employees["e1"].status)
```

and then you can use the input string to subscript `employees` as well.

```
who = input("Who: ")
print(employees[who].status)
```

Answer (score 0):

one other approach is to use sys module:

```
import sys

# class definitions etc


while True:
    try:
        cmd = input("Cmd: ")

        if cmd == "status_check":
            who = input("Who: ")
            atr = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], who)
            print(atr.status)
```